# How to insert a hyphen between numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, string, loops, numbers

I want to make a script in PHP which displays the numbers and a hyphen between the numbers. It should look like this:

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
```

I have the following script right now, but the problem is it displays a hyphen at the end of the numbers:

```
$x = 1;
$h = 1;
while($x <= 10) {
    echo "$x";
    $x++;

    if($h < $x){
        echo "-";
        $h++;                
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is simpler way to do this work. Use [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to create array contain numbers and use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join target array with string.

```
echo implode("-", range(1, 10));
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/DTmej)

Comment: This is a good solution, assuming the numbers are sequential (which they are in the question)

Comment: @JeremyHarris: Using a loop they would have to be sequential, at least incrementing by a specifc number which is what the third param of `range()` is used for ;-)

Comment: Huh, wasn't aware of the 3rd parameter. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @JeremyHarris: Just for fun, check `range(10, 1)` and `range('A', 'z')`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Oh, you are *wicked* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Insert the hypen before the number, except for the first number.

```
$x = 1;
while($x <= 10) {
    if($x > 1)
        echo '-';
    echo $x;
    $x++;               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use temp string

```
<?php    

  $x = 1;
  $str ='';
  while($x <= 10) {
       if ($str  == '') {
         $str = $x;
       } else {
        $str = $str .'-'.$x;
       }
  } 
  echo $str; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem (I don't know why you use the h variable):

```
<?php    
    $x = 1;
    $result="";
    while($x <= 10) {
        $result.=$x."-";              
    }  
    echo substr($result, 0,-1);

?>
```

or use the implode function